# Java: How to use the compareTo method to check the order of 2 nodes

Tags: java, list, comparable, compareto

I am working on a programming assignment and I could use some help understanding the compareTo method.

One of the questions of the assignment is to add an incoming element to a list. If the list is sorted, I am supposed to put the new node in its correct position. The list can be either sorted in an ascending or descending order. I thought I could check which is the order by comparing the head node to the node after (node.getNext()) but I am not sure. The line of code that I am not sure on is the following:

```
if(head.getContent().compareTo(tp.getContent())==1)
```

head is the first node is a generic data type T, which has already been added. tp is head.getNext() just to save space and is also a generic data type T, since I am sure I will be typing it again. I did not write a compareTo method on the program because the professor told me that simply call the compareTo method to compare another generic data type. Also, I am not sure on the difference between:

```
extends Comparable<T>
```

and

```
implements Comparable<T>
```

but the assignment requires me to use the first one.

if the head node element is 1 and the next on is 3, what will the output of the if statement be? true or false?

Comment: While creating class you can `extend` other classes and `implement` interfaces. `Comparable` is interface.

Comment: @Pshemo: interfaces can `extend` other interfaces

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz you are right, I corrected my comment.

Comment: @all can someone explain why one will extend a marker interface like cloneable to create a new custom interface.

Comment: @user1546706 I guess professor ask what is expected to be learned. It's time to buy any book on Java programming language. The difference between extends Comparable<T> and implements Comparable<T> (and even more) would be more clear ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically the way to think of compareTo is to *ALWAYS* put a zero on the other side of it and then imagine that the operator is between the two arguments.

```
A.compareTo(B) == 0; // A == B
A.compareTo(B) > 0; // A > B
A.compareTo(B) >= 0; // A >= B

//etc etc etc
```

This makes it much easier to read and saves you trying to figure out what you actually meant by `>-1` or something in two years

Comment: Additionally: `Comparator` does __NOT__ require `-1` or `+1`, instead `-42` and `+64` will do also. Always comparing to `0` will take care of this also once and forever.

Comment: this is actually a great way to see it, I find myself using this little table over and over again. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of your question, `Comparable<T>` is an interface that defines a single method: `compareTo()`.

- Use `extends Comparable<T>` to create a sub-interface that adds more methods to Comparable.
- Use `implements Comparable<T>` for a concrete *class* that implements the interface.

If the professor wants you to use `extends Comparable` then perhaps he wants you to create an interface for your nodes, something like this:

```
public interface Node<T> extends Comparable<Node<?>> {

    T getContent();
}
```

Comment: can u explain why one would extend a marker interface to create a new interface.

Comment: @Algorithmist And where did you get that `Comparable` is a marker interface?

Comment: It's not a marker interface as it contains the `compareTo()` method. `ScheduledFuture<T>` is an example of an interface that extends `Comparable<T>`.

Comment: @all sorry for that mistake.I was talking about cloneable interface.

Comment: Note that the return value of `getContent()` is the one that is `Comparable`, not the `Node`. However, OP should probably let `Node implements Comparable<Node>` so that it delegates to comparing `getContent`.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the documentation for the [comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Object%29) interface which defines the compareTo method.  Then you will know what the return value means in terms of the sorting order of your list.

Comparable is an interface.  An interface can extend another interface.  A class can implement an interface.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use `java.lang.Comparable` **interface**.

```
public interface Comparable<T>{
    public int compareTo(){
    }
}
```

**2.** Your **class needs to implement Comparable**, and then **each element will be calling** `compareTo()` **on each other** to sort themselves.

**3.** If you **want to sort in more than one way**..then use`java.util.Comparator`, which use `compare()` method

Comment: kumar please do not bold the words.Although it would make your post more visible then others :).please edit it.I already edited your last post.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but there is no written rule abt the use of bold letters, and its ok if it doesnt messes up with the answer.. i have already receive appreciation for using the bold letters in a proper way on this site... but still i will try my best to not use the bold whenever not necessary

Answer (score 0):

The Comparable interface simply says that you must have a way of comparing two objects A and B, both of type T, and that, as Affe notes, you should return 1 if A > B, 0 if A and B are equal, and -1 if A < B.  Note that equal does not mean == as in Java == means "do these two object references refer to the same thing", not "are these two objects essentially the same."

It does not, however, define how you must compare them; whichever class implements it must do so.  You can say that A is greater than B based on the value of some field in type T, or you can do something more complex.  Since a lower integer value, for example, indicates a higher priority (1 < 2, but a priority one issue is higher-up than a priority two issue), the basis of comparison is not always apparent, but in your case, if you have a series of nodes whose contents are integers, it would make sense to say compare two nodes as you would their integer values; e.g. if the integer value stored in A is greater than the integer value stored in B, A > B so A.compareTo(B) returns 1.

As for the direction to use extends rather than implements - well, when you are using generic types (such as T), you use extends rather than implements.  When you are defining a class, implements means that you are using the method headers of an interface, and when you are defining an interface, extends means that you are using the interface as a superinterface, much like a superclass to a class.  So if you say that Class A implements Comparable, you are saying that A must have a method to compare itself to classes which implement Comparable.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UseComparetoMethod{

    static String arr[] = {"Ram", "Bharat", "Laxman", "Satrughna"};

    public static void main(String ar[]) {

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[j].compareTo(arr[i]) < 0) {
                    String t = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = t;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

[A completer description here](http://stringpool.com)

Answer (score 0):

package example;

import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author pradeep
 */
public class ComparableDemo {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    User u = new User();
    u.setName("pradeep");
    User u1 = new User();
    u1.setName("Ajeet");
    User u2 = new User();
    u2.setName("sameer");
    List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
    list.add(u);
    list.add(u1);
    list.add(u2);
    Collections.sort(list);
    for (User user : list) {
        System.out.println(user.getName());
    }
}
```

}

class User implements Comparable {

```
private String name;

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(User n) {
    if (this.getName().compareTo(n.getName()) > 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (this.getName().compareTo(n.getName()) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}[you can learn more about java here!!](http://pkjavacode.wordpress.com)